# Use replace to update column value from another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, sql-update

I have database that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE code (
  id SERIAL, 
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO code (name) VALUES ('random_value1_random');
INSERT INTO code (name) VALUES ('random_value123_random');

CREATE TABLE value (
  id SERIAL, 
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO value (name) VALUES ('value1');
INSERT INTO value (name) VALUES ('value123');

UPDATE code SET name = REPLACE(name, SELECT name from value , '');
```

I want to update my table `code` to remove a portion of a code and that code is coming from another table. My goal is to update all values of `code` and remove the portion of the string that matches another value. My end goal is to make all `code.name` in the example look like: `random_random` removing the value from the `value` table.

When tried using to replace with a query I get an error:

> [21000] ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

What is a cleaner better way to do this?

Comment: In `REPLACE(name, SELECT name from value , '');` your select statement returns all rows from `value` table. You need to return only one row. in that SELECT query. I guess you need something like `UPDATE code SET name = REPLACE(name, SELECT name from value where id = code.id , '');
`

Comment: Please show your version of Postgres. Make clear which rows in table `values` shall be applied to which rows in table `code`. Be aware that the sequence of replacements is relevant. So, if more than one row applies, define their sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace multiple substrings in a string. You can use `STRING_AGG` to get the search pattern from the single search values.

```
UPDATE code SET name = 
  REGEXP_REPLACE( name,
                  (SELECT '(' || STRING_AGG(name, '|') || ')' from value),
                  ''
                );
```

This will leave you with 'random___random', not 'random_random'. If you only want to look for substrings separated with the underline character, then use

```
UPDATE code SET name = 
  TRIM('_' FROM 
        REGEXP_REPLACE(name, 
                       (SELECT '(' || STRING_AGG('_?' || name || '_?', '|') || ')' from value),
                       '_'
                      )
      );
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/RrOel8Ns

Answer (score -1):

This T-SQL (I don't have Postgres) and isn't elegant, but it works..

```sql
;with l as (
    -- Match the longest value first
    select c.id c_id, v.id v_id, ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by c.id order by len(v.name) desc) r
    from code c
    join value v on charindex (v.name, c.name) > 0)
, l1 as (
    -- Select the longest value first
    select c_id, v_id from l where r = 1
    )
update c set name = REPLACE(c.name, v.name, '')
from l1
join code c on c.id = l1.c_id
join value v on v.id = l1.v_id
```